# GitLab CI variable incrementing

Tags: variables, continuous-integration, gitlab

Tell me, please, how to realize the ability to display the current version of ci-job in the naming of artifacts? current:

artifacts:
name: “demo_integration_javafx_scell-b(there could be current version of job)”

Answer (score 0):

In your job, just append the files with the `$CI_JOB_ID` variable and add the folder in the artifacts section of your pipeline

Comment: sorry cant fully understand what means "just append the files with the $CI_JOB_ID variable"? ( im true newby in this one :( )

Comment: You need knowledge of shell scripts, read this article https://linuxize.com/post/bash-concatenate-strings/